# Launching Alliance of Valiant Arms WITHOUT Reactor or Steam

Tags: steam

I love the game, but there is one problem.
The launcher comes with a huge drawback.
**Reactor** uses ~100mb of ram and some CPU.
**Steam** uses ~170mb of ram and a bit more CPU.

Still, 100 and 170mb are a bit too much.
Is there a way to launch the game without Reactor/Steam? :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a game require Steam, there is no legal way of launching it without Steam running (I don't know about Reactor, but it should be the same thing).

On the other hand, there are way of reducing the memory and CPU consumption of Steam:

- Make sure to pause any downloads before starting your game (Steam should do it automatically, but better safe than sorry);
- Disable the Steam overlay (for just a game, right click on the name of the game, properties, uncheck the Steam community box. You can do it for all games in the option menu).

With this, you can keep Steam's memory consumption under 50MB of private memory, and cpu usage low enough to not worry on a dual core CPU.

[image: Memory and CPU usage of steam during play]

Comment: How comes Procexp shows ~150mb of RAM while Task Manager shows ~18-30mb of RAM?

Comment: Either ProceXP uses bits and the Task Manager use Bytes to show the memory usage (a byte being 8 bits), or ProceXP show you the total committed memory (virtual memory reserved by the OS), whereas the task manager only show Private memory, physical memory which can not be shared with another program.  Going to the resource monitor give me a 200MB of committed memory for Steam, where 60MB are used, 45MB of which are private.

Answer (score 0):

No. The game needs either of those.

The lesser of two evils(!) in your case would be Reactor, due to the smaller memory footprint.